# How to get Adtran TA5000 23 firmware information with an SNMP request?

Tags: routing, router, snmp, linux

I'm looking for any SNMP request that I could use through a Linux terminal to get the firmware information of all our ADTRAN DSLAMs that we currently have in the field(there are close to 18,000).

I found this command: `snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 2c` but it's not polling the firmware version.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic unfortunately.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

snmpwalk -v 2c -c   .1.3.6.1.4.1.664.5.13.2.4.1.6

Comment: You should provide some details with your answer - what MIB this comes from, what it has been tested with, ...